# Angular 2 Route Guard Confiability

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm developing an application that requires user authentication if you want to display certain pages ... I'm a little worried about letting the angular 2 guard handle all the permissions, should I add some verification in the backend that says if the user can or can't access a given URL? Is there a way that someone in the frontend can inject javascript code into my page and access a forbidden context by making the canActivate guard return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I add some verification in the backend that says if the user can or can't access a given URL?

**Yes**, you have to give roles to users, and send it to client, so the app decide locally if it can serve this url. **BUT** you have to keep this role/user association on server side too, because someone can edit the request.
Your server will only send data if your association says the user is authorized.

> Is there a way that someone in the frontend can inject javascript code into my page and access a forbidden context by making the canActivate guard return true?

Sure, but even if it wasn't possible, you must **never** trust a client request.
Only trust your server side information, and compare it with the client request.

Comment: +1. Just curious but can't anyone just view the protected UI's or pages by simply modifying the javascript (by injecting false values)? Is there any way to absolutely make sure that the users cannot view the routes or the pages that they are not supposed to view (including the UI)?  I understand we can protect the data by adding security on the server side to the API calls, but what about the UI? (sorry new to Angular excuse my ignorance).

Comment: Indeed, if your admin interface is host on the same website than your client interface, it is technically possible to bypass the guards. This is one of the reasons why it is mandatory to protect APIs. If you really need to protect admin interfaces, you can host it on another website, like admin.mywebsite.com